# Python and websockets - send audio stream

Tags: python, websocket

I have set up a socket server and send the messages to all connected clients. I'm sending data from python to javascript.
I want to send my microphone input to all clients listening.
So in my Python application I do the following

```
import pyaudio
import websocket
import json
import struct
import wave
import pickle

#record
CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 40

HOST = 'ws://127.0.0.1:8080'

s = websocket.create_connection(HOST)

s.send('Hii')

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

for i in range(0, p.get_device_count()):
    print(i, p.get_device_info_by_index(i)['name'])

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,
                input_device_index=1)

print("*recording")

i = 0
frames = []

while i < 20:
    data  = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)
    print(i)
    i += 1

s.send(pickle.dumps(frames))
```

The `send('hi')` is send and received by the other connections.
I tried sending the frames without an encoding, which gives me

```
TypeError: an integer is required
```

If I encode the frames (with `pickle.dumps()`, the application runs, but the server nor the clients receive them. Also `json.dumps()` doesn't work.

```
raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: b'\x7f\x03\xa1\x03\x7f\x03=\x03 ...
```

if I encode the frames to a string, the script runs and no error is encountered.

I'm just trying this. But what I really want to achieve is to put the `send` inside the loop and stream the input directly to the server. When I do this, I get the following error

```
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

I can see that the loop runs twice and then hits the error. Why? Do I need to compress the stream?

Any advice?

Comment: Have you hear about icecast2?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
s.send(pickle.dumps(frames), opcode=websocket.ABNF.OPCODE_BINARY)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That doesn't get send either. I noticed parsing the data to a string and sending them works. So I'll try it that way